# How to let ajax delay to request url

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I do an assignment for my project. I have to use ajax to update the mysql without refresh webpage.

I have 2 php file, first is `a.php` and code as below (view user credit):

```
if($_GET['do'] == 'viewcredit'){
    $quser = DB::query("SELECT * FROM ".DB::table('game_jnship_user')." WHERE uid = '$_G[uid]'");
    $ruser = DB::fetch($quser);
    //$moneyN = $ruser['money'];
    echo $ruser['money'];
}
```

second php file is `b.php` and code as below (do some action):

```
$quser = DB::query("SELECT * FROM ".DB::table('game_jnship_user')." WHERE uid = '$_G[uid]'");
$ruser = DB::fetch($quser);
$moneyN = $ruser['money'];
$gcoin = $ruser['gcoin'];
if($_GET['do'] == 'treasurehunt'){
    $moneyadd = $moneyN + 1;
    DB::query("UPDATE ".DB::table('game_jnship_user')." SET money = '$moneyadd' WHERE uid = '$_G[uid]'");
}
```

My `html` code as below:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".submit_button").click(function() {
        var url = "a.php?do=viewcredit";
        var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(url);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: decodedUrl,
            cache: true,
            success: function(html){
            jQuery("#money").html(html);
            }  
        });
    });
});
</script>
<div id="money">$ruser[money]</div>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showWindow('jn_spop', 'b.php?do=treasurehunt')" class="c_button submit_button"><strong>Confirm</strong></a>
```

So, now when I click the last row of `html`, the `<a>Confirm</a>`, for the first time, the `<div id="money">$ruser[money]</div>` will not give the latest result.

Ok, let say the `$ruser[money] = '1';`, after I click the `<a>Confirm</a>`, mysql has been update the `money` to `2`, but the `<div id="money">$ruser[money]</div>` still showing 1. After I click `<a>Confirm</a>` Once again, the `<div id="money">$ruser[money]</div>` showing `2` (but mysql has been update `money` to `3` already.)

So, if I want the `ajax` delay to do the `a.php?do=viewcredit`, is it possible? of is it have otherway I can get the latest `$ruser[money]` without refresh webpage?

Thank you.

Comment: you need to fetch the result of your `b.php` and tells it to ajax to show off the result to html

Comment: You have two `onclick` event handlers. If you need to update `div#money` after manipulation on server named `treasurehunt`, you can move code of `viewcredit` inside `showWindow`. I can`t show you how, because implementation is missing.

Comment: Or you can return actual `$ruser['money']` at `treasurehunt` and update `div#money`

Comment: You should update `#money` div after the `update` operation as well.

Comment: @DimaFitiskin I could not add the `viewcredit` inside `showWindow`, it must be separate for 2 php, so I want to find out is it any other way can do as well...

Comment: @swee-hong it can be separate for 2 php, but you have a chain of requests. Retrieve of `viewcredit` not make sense before `treasurehunt` action. Show me `showWindow` implementation.

Comment: @DimaFitiskin I have use `sleep` in php, 1s for `b.php` then 2s for `a.php`, is works, but depends on the internet speed condition also, after I was thinking about other way, so I add 1 more confirm button after `treasurehunt` result, then when user click the confirm button, the only call the `ajax` function, so solve the problem. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set async: false.
But if your ajax request take time show some loader, so user will understand some action is performing.
for more details please check this link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: decodedUrl,
        cache: true,
        async: false,
        success: function(html){
        jQuery("#money").html(html);
        }  
    });
```